# is highcharts able to render 1000 points per second?

Tags: performance, highcharts, render

recently I'm doing a project showing a spectrum.
Here is the official demo of dynamic update chart:
http://www.hcharts.cn/demo/highstock/dynamic-update

Now i wish to see if i could update 1000 points per second on the chart, specifically, execute addPoint() 1000 times over 1s. I wrote a chunk of code like this:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
  var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
    y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
    console.log(count++);
}
```

soon i found it is unable to render on the web page. Then i console.log a variable, which started from 0 to 1000, after 200 it became very slow. Anyone who could give me a solution? thanks

Comment: It is hard to add so many points on every second in Highcharts and I am not sure why you want to do this by adding point and not just setting data to new one, but if you want to use addPoint, you shouldn't redraw your chart every time you are adding your point. Right now you are redrawing your chart 1000 times per second - the performance just can't be good in this case. Look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/u6j9Lnw8/1/ If this will meet your requirements I will post it as an answer

Comment: thank you ill see if this works:)

Comment: The link just crushed, would u like to repost it?

Comment: This seems not working sir, would u double check your code? the console says cookie is not defined;

Comment: OIC sir, forgive me that im in china, everything is lagged. hmn, this seems to work for current, but it is possible to have animation like what highcharts did?

Comment: I think that your current problem is connected with your xAxis range, it is a little bit to small so when you are adding so many points you are not able to see the animation (because of changing the extremes). I think that when you will set bigger interval, it will look ok

Comment: Hi sir, may i request for one more question, you mentioned just setting data to new one, that is exact what im thinking of which means, other than addPoint() to update the chart meanwhile maintain what's left, is there any other way to do this? thank you very much~

Comment: I am not sure what exactely would you like to achieve. So you want to remove your data and add new one? You can use Series.setData in this case: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData